Highlight cell in first column if row contains a partial text match
I would like to highlight cells in the first column if there is a partial string match in the same row. The spreadsheet has 100 rows and 100 columns. I would like this applied to the majority of the spreadsheet except a couple header rows.
I would like to be able to determine if any of the cells in that row contain the word "missing" and then highlight (fill) the first column in that row. I would also like this to be case insensitive.
I am using Microsoft Office 365 online if that makes any difference.
For example I would want cell A18 highlighted if BB18 was " 0.0   Missing Done  1 ".

You can use the conditional formatting feature. Select the first column and command "Conditional Formatting-->New Rule...":

The formula you need can look like (for the active cell in the row #2 as depicted, otherwise adjust the row number in the formula)
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("missing",B2:K2)))

